# Reactivex NetworkOnMainThreadException even when subcribed

Tags: mvvm, kotlin, rx-java2, reactivex

I'm trying to build an MVVM Kotlin app that uses Reactivex to make the Async calls to the API.

I've seen alot of threads with the same problem but on all of them the OP forgot to put the `subscribeOn` in the call, in my code i do this and still have the network error. I've looked in the debugger to find the problem but to no succes.

```
class NoteViewModel(apiKey : String) : ViewModel () { // , Observable {
private lateinit var noteAdapter : NoteAdapter

private val notesList = MutableLiveData <ArrayList<Note>>()
private var subscription : Disposable
private val noteCollector = NoteCollector()
private val isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

init {
    subscription = noteCollector.getAll(apiKey)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe { onCollectNotesStart() }
            .doOnTerminate { onCollectNotesFinished() }
            .subscribe(
                    { result -> onCollectNotesSuccess(result) },
                    { error -> onCollectNotesError(error) }
            )
}
...
}
```

If you need more info let me know, i'll provide it.

EDIT: added stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: jari.student.hogent.cominghome, PID: 2532
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jari.student.hogent.cominghome/jari.student.hogent.cominghome.Activities.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:200)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:148)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:90)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:190)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:142)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:104)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:410)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:343)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:489)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.toolbox.HttpClient.setBodyIfDoOutput(HttpClient.kt:91)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.toolbox.HttpClient.executeRequest(HttpClient.kt:39)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.TaskRequest.call(TaskRequest.kt:14)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$result$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt:81)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$result$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.github.kittinunf.result.Result$Companion.of(Result.kt:116)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt.response(Deserializable.kt:81)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Request.responseObject(Request.kt:344)
    at jari.student.hogent.cominghome.Models.NoteCollector.getAll(NoteCollector.kt:22)
    at jari.student.hogent.cominghome.ViewModels.NoteViewModel.<init>(NoteViewModel.kt:22)
    at jari.student.hogent.cominghome.ViewModels.CustomViewModelFactory.create(CustomViewModelFactory.kt:11)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102)
    at jari.student.hogent.cominghome.Fragments.NoteFragment.onCreateView(NoteFragment.kt:27)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1340)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7200)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2918)
        ... 9 more
```

EDIT 2: added getAll methode

```
override fun getAll(ApiKey: String): Observable<ArrayList<Note>> {
    val bodyJson: JSONObject = JSONObject()
            .put("apiKey", ApiKey)

    val notesList: ArrayList<Note> = ArrayList()

    val (_, _, result) = path.httpPost()
            .header(mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/json"))
            .body(bodyJson.toString())
            .responseObject(Note.Deserializer())
    val (notes, err) = result
    if (err != null){
        throw err.exception
    }
    notes?.forEach { note ->
        notesList.add(note)
    }

    return Observable.fromArray(notesList)
}
```

Comment: What `onCollectLocationsStart()` and `onCollectLocationsFinished()` do?

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin `isLoading.value = false` or true ofcourse, depending on the methode

Comment: Maybe someone have played an angry joke and made something like `RxJavaPlugins.setIoScheduler(scheduler -> AndroidSchedulers.mainThead())`?

Comment: Also, if you would put a stacktrace - it would be just great

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin also tried `Schedulers.newThread()` so don't think so. I'll edit with a stacktrace

Comment: Hmmm... `at jari.student.hogent.cominghome.ViewModels.NoteViewModel.<init>(NoteViewModel.kt:22)` - are you sure that we are seeking an error in the right `ViewModel`

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin uploaded the wrong code. But they are the same, just getting different objects. Edited the code.

Comment: Could you please show the insides of `getAll()` method of `NoteCollector`?

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your `getAll` implementation to this:

```
override fun getAll(ApiKey: String): Observable<ArrayList<Note>> 
    = Observable.create { emitter -> 
        val bodyJson: JSONObject = JSONObject()
                .put("apiKey", ApiKey)

        val notesList: ArrayList<Note> = ArrayList()

        val (_, _, result) = path.httpPost()
                .header(mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/json"))
                .body(bodyJson.toString())
                .responseObject(Note.Deserializer())
        val (notes, err) = result
        if (err != null) {
            throw err.exception
        }
        notes?.forEach { note ->
            notesList.add(note)
        }
        emitter.onNext(notesList)
    }
```

Comment: I get a type mismatch on `emitter.onNext(note)` it requires an arraylist not a note.